# powershell equivalent for curl command

Tags: powershell, curl

Looking for a powershell equivalent to the following CURL command:

```
curl -x "http://username:password@192.168.1.1:5001" "https://www.google.com"
```

Have looked online but could not find anything similar to this.

Comment: Start by figuring out what curl's parameters do. Then take a look at Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest. Is this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/a/591311) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell equivalent would be the following command:

```
Invoke-Webrequest -Proxy "http://username:password@192.168.1.1:5001" -Uri "https://www.google.com"
```